# Getting the Item ID from the ECB (Edit Control Block) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, ecb-menu

I know I can use {ItemId} to pass it to the URL like so:

```
<UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/ConvertItem/ConvertItem.aspx?ListId={ListId}&amp;ItemId={ItemId}&amp;ItemUrl={ItemUrl}"/>
```

However, I am using JavaScript exclusively.  Can I get the ItemID using JavaScript?

```
<UrlAction Url="javascript:function copyListItems() { res = SPListItemCopy.Resources[_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage];var listItemID = {ItemId};var listId = {ListId};var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);var item = list.getItemById(listItemID); ..."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the token should be getting replaced anyway, is you second example not working ? also you might nee to wrap the vars with single quotes like var listId = '{ListId}' also your JavaScript functions is not self calling, I think it should be javascript: function copyListItems(){}()